# How to return that all threads are finished in a function?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, web-services

I have this code that starts some threads by iterating through a list of strings and send each one to a `Sub` which connects to a webservice and waits for a result:

```
Public Shared Function StartThreading(names As String())
        Dim threads As List(Of Thread) = New List(Of Thread)()
        For Each name In names
            Dim t As Thread = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(Sub() CallWebService(name)))
            threads.Add(t)
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To threads.Count - 1
            Dim t = threads(i)
            Dim name = names(i)
            t.Start(name)
        Next
        For Each t As Thread In threads
            t.Join()
        Next
    End Function
```

The Sub for the webservice caller is:

```
Public Shared Sub CallWebService(inputxml As String)
        Dim _url = "http://10.231.58.173:8080/ps/services/ProcessServer?WSDL"
        Dim _action = "http://10.231.58.173:8080/ps/services/ProcessServer"
        Dim soapEnvelopeXml As XmlDocument = CreateSoapEnvelope(inputxml)
        Dim webRequest As HttpWebRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action)
            Dim appPath As String = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
            Dim configpath As String = appPath + "\Config.ini"
            Dim configdata As IniData = Functii.ReadIniFile(configpath)
            Dim outputxmlsave = configdata("PATHS")("OUTPUTXML")
            InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest)
            Dim asyncResult As IAsyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(Nothing, Nothing)
            asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()
            Dim soapResult As String
        Using webResponse As WebResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult)
            Using rd As StreamReader = New StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
            File.WriteAllText(outputxmlsave & "\" & "test.xml", soapResult.ToString)
            Console.Write(soapResult)
        End Using
    End Sub
```

How can I know that all threads are done successfully or not? Is there something I can use to return a `True` value if they are all done?

Comment: Please don't tag random languages, this question has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: Rather than using `Threads` explicitly, it would be more appropriate to use `Tasks`.  They can return a value and provide other state information.  If you want to stick with `Threads`, just increment an `Integer` field on each success using `Interlocked`.  When all threads have completed, compare that number to the number of threads to see the success rate.